# Get web api response with HttpClient MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, http, asp.net-web-api

I have an URL of API. I want to make an action in controller to get all data

BranchesController.cs:

```
 public Task<IEnumerable<BranchVm>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        string baseUrl = "http://api.diamond.smart-gate.net/api/Branches/GetBranches";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var task = client.GetStringAsync(baseUrl);
        return task.ContinueWith<IEnumerable<BranchVm>>(innerTask =>
        {
            var json = innerTask.Result;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BranchVm[]>(json);
        });
    }
```

Branch.js:

```
 columns: [
 {
    "data": 'branchArName',
    "name": "branchArName",
    "autoWidth": true,
    "orderable": true
   },
    {
   "data": 'branchEnName',
   "name": "branchEnName",
   "autoWidth": true,
   "orderable": true,
   },
 ],
   ajax: {
      url: "/Branches/GetAllAsync",
      dataSrc: ''
 }
```

It doesn't return any data but when I debug it , I have all data in innerTaslk.Result but var json equals null. so, I don't know why ?

Comment: This is working fine for me, how are you calling this method?

Comment: i use path of this method in js file ... when i debug i got var json = null :/

Comment: Why not make the method properly async then? No need for the `ContinueWith` stuff.

Comment: So , What should i do ?

Comment: I mean something like [this](https://gist.github.com/WiredUK/aa0d50b6ab9249e923f4206d154d6f8c)

Comment: yes , now var json equals my data but i still can't display them in the table

Comment: That's a different problem completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to do async code without using async. That method is much simpler if you use proper `async` syntax. This should solve problems with how you are calling it:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<BranchVm>> GetAllAsync()
//     ^^^^^
//     Make the method async
{
    string baseUrl = "http://api.diamond.smart-gate.net/api/Branches/GetBranches";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var json = await client.GetStringAsync(baseUrl);
    //         ^^^^^
    //         await the async call instead of messing around with tasks
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BranchVm[]>(json);
}
```